# Why is the SqlDatasource I am using not returning a calculated value when the same query does in SQL server? C#.net 4.0

Tags: c#-4.0, sqldatasource

Query that works in Sql Server.

```
Declare @from datetime, @to datetime, @status int, @SupervisorID uniqueidentifier
SELECT @to = '09-12-2012', @from = '02-02-2012', @status = 0, @SupervisorID = '2EB087F0-A419-4421-861A-6EBDFED9449A'

select nums.date as DayOff, [RequestID], [EmployeeName], [AbsenceType], [AbsenceBundle], [DateRequested], [FirstDay], [LastDay], [ReturnDay], [SupervisorName], [DaysHoursDesc] as DaysAbsent, [Description], Hours from
            (select dateadd(day, number, @from) as date
            from 
                (select distinct number from Numbers
                ) num
            where dateadd(day, number, @from) < @to) nums right outer join [AbsenceRequests].[dbo].[AbsenceRequestWithDescriptions] a on (DateDiff(Day, a.FirstDay, nums.date) >= 0 and DateDiff(Day, a.LastDay, nums.date) <=0)
            where
                 (([SupervisorID] = @SupervisorID) or ([EmployeeID] = @SupervisorID)
                            or 
                 ([SupervisorID] in  (select SupervisorID from Viewers where [viewerID] = @SupervisorID)))
and((@status = StatusID) or (@status = '0'))
            order by SupervisorName, EmployeeName, FirstDay, Hours
```

Results I am getting from this query

```
2012-06-06 00:00:00.000 515 apptest1    Vacation    55 - Vacation   2012-06-28 00:00:00.000 2012-06-06 00:00:00.000 2012-06-07 00:00:00.000 2012-06-08 00:00:00.000 apptest3    16 Hour(s)  Pending 16
```

SqlDatasource definition

```
  <asp:SqlDataSource ID="EmployeeAbsenceRequestsSql" runat="server"  
        ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:AbsenceRequestsConnectionString %>" 

            SelectCommand="
            select nums.date as DayOff, [RequestID], [EmployeeName], [AbsenceType], [AbsenceBundle], [DateRequested], [FirstDay], [LastDay], [ReturnDay], [SupervisorName], [DaysHoursDesc] as DaysAbsent, [Description], Hours from
            (select dateadd(day, number, @from) as date
            from 
                (select distinct number from Numbers
                ) num
            where dateadd(day, number, @from) &lt; @to) nums right outer join [AbsenceRequests].[dbo].[AbsenceRequestWithDescriptions] a on (DateDiff(Day, a.FirstDay, nums.date) &gt;= 0 and DateDiff(Day, a.LastDay, nums.date) &lt;=0)
            where
                 (([SupervisorID] = @SupervisorID) or ([EmployeeID] = @SupervisorID)
                            or 
                 ([SupervisorID] in  (select SupervisorID from Viewers where [viewerID] = @SupervisorID)))
                 and ((@status = StatusID) or (@status = '0'))
            order by SupervisorName, EmployeeName, FirstDay, Hours " 
            onselecting="EmployeeAbsenceRequestsSql_Selecting" >
            <SelectParameters>
                <asp:FormParameter DefaultValue=" " FormField="Fromtxt" Name="from" />
                <asp:FormParameter DefaultValue=" " FormField="Totxt" Name="to" />
                <asp:SessionParameter DefaultValue="&quot;&quot;" Name="SupervisorID" 
                    SessionField="EmployeeID" Type="Object" />
                <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="Statusddl" DefaultValue="0" PropertyName="SelectedValue"  Name="status" />
            </SelectParameters>
        </asp:SqlDataSource>
```

I am getting results with this when I call the select method of the datasource but the First Column DayOff is returning blank(I have verified this by setting a watch and checking the DataView). Below is the code that I am using to execute and read the results of the select query.

```
   protected void RefreshTreeview()
    {
        this.EmployeeAbsenceRequestsSql.SelectParameters["from"].DefaultValue = SafeDateString(this.Fromtxt.Text);
        this.EmployeeAbsenceRequestsSql.SelectParameters["to"].DefaultValue = SafeDateString(this.Totxt.Text);
        DataView dv = (DataView) this.EmployeeAbsenceRequestsSql.Select(new DataSourceSelectArguments());

        FillTreeView(dv);
    }

private void FillTreeView(DataView dv)
{
    TreeNode CurrentSupervisorNode =  null;
    TreeNode CurrentEmployeeNode = null;
    foreach (DataRow row in dv.Table.Rows)
    {
        String SupervisorName = SafeString(row["SupervisorName"]);
        if ((CurrentSupervisorNode == null) || !CurrentSupervisorNode.Text.Equals(SupervisorName))
        {
            CurrentSupervisorNode = new TreeNode(SupervisorName);
            this.AbsencesTV.Nodes.Add(CurrentSupervisorNode);
            CurrentEmployeeNode = null;
        }
        String EmployeeName = SafeString(row["EmployeeName"]);
        if (CurrentEmployeeNode == null || !CurrentEmployeeNode.Text.Equals(EmployeeName))
        {
            CurrentEmployeeNode = new TreeNode(EmployeeName);
            CurrentSupervisorNode.ChildNodes.Add(CurrentEmployeeNode);
        }

        String DayOffSummary = SafeString(row["DayOff"]) + " " + SafeString(row["AbsenceBundle"]) +" " + SafeString(row["Description"]);
        CurrentEmployeeNode.ChildNodes.Add(new TreeNode(DayOffSummary));
    }
}
```

Does anyone have any debugging advice or even better the answer to why this is happening?

Comment: Do you have a version of SQL Server that comes with SQL Server profiler? I would start by looking at it there to see what is really going on at the DB.

Comment: I have SQL Server profiler but I have not used it before. Do you know of a good reference that lets me better use it to figure out what is going on?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to the great comment by simon I was able to find out that the default blank value for @to was being passed instead of a default I was trying to use. When I specified a date for the @to value I got the results I was expecting.